# Should v-for key property be globally unique or unique within a particular v-for

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

The docs are not particularly clear on how unique the `key` property should be within a `v-for`. I am guessing that they should be unique within a specific instance of a `v-for` and that you could have to separate `v-for` that have elements with the same key.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#key

If I have a component that has two instances on my page that have a v-for, can they both have elements with the same key?

Comment: It should be fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a unique key within the `v-for`. Vue uses it to correlate DOM elements with viewmodel elements in a particular list. There's no potential confusion between elements inside a `v-for` and those outside it, otherwise every element would need a `key`.

Comment: According to the docs it appears to be used outside of v-for (maybe internally): "Since it’s a generic mechanism for Vue to identify nodes, the key also has other uses that are not specifically tied to v-for, as we will see later in the guide." But I cant find any other relevant mention of key in the docs.

Comment: As a generic mechanism to identify nodes, it may be useful in other ways (though I don't recall seeing any examples of such), but its use in `v-for` is to keep track of which nodes go with which item when the data changes.

Comment: Further confirmation on the vue forum here: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/v-for-key-does-the-key-need-to-be-unique-across-the-entire-component/28040

Answer (score 2):

There is a slight nuance actually: keys need to be unique *for all children of a parent element*...

So, if you have two elements with v-for directives that are children of the same parent, those two elements must *not* share the same keys!

This was the situation that confused me the other day (the two xTick and yTick arrays could both contain the value '0', and this was causing a conflict!)

```
 <g>
  <line
    v-for="(position) in xTicks"
    :key="position.toString()"
    ...
  />
  <line
    v-for="(position) in yTicks"
    :key="position.toString()"
    ...
  />
</g>
```

Solved by prefixing keys like

```
`xtick-${position.toString()}`
```

Reference: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/v-for-key-does-the-key-need-to-be-unique-across-the-entire-component/28040